# How can I debug 502 errors on my ASP.NET web application in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm wondering if any of you can recommend some steps for how I can debug

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

errors in my web app that is hosted on Azure. The problem is that I cannot consistently reproduce them and they seem to magically go away given enough time. For example, I was getting them sporadically on Friday, but after leaving my site up all weekend it was working fine today ... until I deployed it again with changes that can't possible effect the server (basic presentation-level changes). Sometimes I get `502` for static assets such as images.

How can I figure out what is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried VS remote debugging? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/11/04/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 0):

My answer seems a bit late but perhaps this article may help.

[Troubleshoot HTTP errors of "502 bad gateway" and "503 service unavailable" in your Azure web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503)

The article suggests three specific tasks:

1. Observe and monitor application behavior
2. Collect data
3. Mitigate the issue

Perhaps these suggestions are helpful when hosting in Azure but from my perspective the content isn't very deep.